# Object shows up pink even when selecting and adding material?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, faces

Im very new to blender and was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YdA-J27YPU&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eTHFZ2XPkM6gLK8XdsdzNl&index=12) tutorial.

I downloaded the guy's start file to start editing; I had to download the .blend file and textures separately. I don't necessarily want/need to apply the texture, however, without it, no matter what I do, my object shows up pink:

[image]

I have tried selecting all faces in *Edit Mode* or even just 1 face, creating a simple green material and assigning it as in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrMhbuC8aM0) tutorial, but the material is not applied.

How can I make the object not pink anymore? How can I assign a material or texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's showing up pink because you're actually viewing this model in texture mode, as indicated by this icon.

[image: icon]

You can reassign the texture image in the **Texture** panel, or see the name of the missing image in *File->External Data->Report Missing Files*.

Comment: Thanks. Whenever I go to try to apply a texture (like i would a material), despite my sticking the texture on a UV map and following what most tutorials say I can never get the material to show up on the character. Are there any tutorials you'd recommend? Also do textures show up in game engines (i.e. unity)?

Comment: The tutorials are likely for Cycles, you're using Blender Render where materials and textures are separated. There are many great sources of tutorials like CG Cookie, BlenderGuru, and Gleb Alexandrov's videos that may help you. As for the last question, Unity may be able to import the materials but I wouldn't count on it happening automatically. In most engines you have to import the texture and model separately, make a material using the texture, and apply it to the model.